# Looking for MongoDB schema suggestions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and I'm wondering what the *"best"* solution would be for handling the following type of data in my database.

---

**Collections:**

- Users
- Lessons

**Overview:**

*Note: Think of the implementation to be similiar to Duolingo or some other learning site.*

**Users** have all the standard generic user information *but* they also need to track how many points, words learned, percentage complete, and so on, that they have for each given **lesson** they've started.

**Lessons** have data like: words learned, total points, words to review, etc.

---

**Picture**

Example of what a user would see in the widget when they view a lesson they've already started...

[image: What a user would see in the widget when they view a lesson's overview that they've already started]

---

So what's a good way to handle this? I feel that I will need at a minimum a collection for **users** and **lessons**, but where would I store that user specific data relating to lessons they've taken?

**What I've thought of so far ...**

```
// user collection
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String },
  lastName: { type: String },
  gender: { type: String, enum: ['male', 'female', 'other'] },
  admin: Boolean,

  address: {
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: {
      type: String,
      uppercase: true,
      required: true,
      enum: statesArray,
    },
    zip: Number,
  },

});

// lesson_results collection
const LessonResultsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  results: [
    {
      id: Number,
      lesson_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      pointsEarned: Number,
      wordsLearned: Number,
      wordsToPractice: [
        {
          id: Number,
          correct: Number,
          incorrect: Number,
          bookmarked: Boolean,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

// lesson collection
const LessonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    totalPoints: Number,
    totalWords: Number,
    words: [
      { 
        id: Number,
        word: String,
        points: Number
      }
    ]
})


     // if logged in
      // find user in user collection 
      // find user's results in lessonsResults collection by using user_id
      // iterate over each result to find their lesson & lesson's data
      // combine data and send to frontend
      // calculate percentage complete + other calculations
      // render aggregate data on screen
```

I'm curious how you would resolve this.

Apologies if it's a bit long-winded! (+ hopefully the examples make sense)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the reference of user in `LessonSchema`, so that you can track how many lessons are taken by a user.

```
const LessonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'UserSchema',required:true},
    title: String,
    description: String,
    totalPoints: Number,
    totalWords: Number,
    words: [
      { 
        id: Number,
        word: String,
        points: Number
      }
    ]
})
```

And you need to maintain a `FLAG` in `LessonResultsSchema` to track whether a user has completed that lesson or not. Once the lesson gets completed, you need to update the `pointsEarned` so that you can have the updated points data.

```
const LessonResultsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  completed:{type:Boolean, default:0},
  results: [
    {
      id: Number,
      lesson_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      pointsEarned: Number,
      wordsLearned: Number,
      wordsToPractice: [
        {
          id: Number,
          correct: Number,
          incorrect: Number,
          bookmarked: Boolean,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});
```